# SmoothDivScroll; Left HotSpot too fast, Right HotSpot does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently using SmoothDivScroll to implement a rolling stream of images. However, the left Hotspot is going too fast, while the Right Hotspot does not seem to respond properly.

I've set up a fiddle showcasing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gUewB/4/

I'm guessing this has something to do with the way the offset is calculated, but I can't find a good fix to solve the issue. My JavaSkills just aren't that great. :/

Comment: Pesonally for me that thing is not working. `el.data("scrollableArea").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {` -> `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mousewheel' `

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is kind of old. But I had the exact same issue! Even I updated to the latest version (which is at moment of posting version 1.3)

The solution from Pieter Mathys unfortunatelly didn't work for me.

I've found out that the scrolling problem occures if the width of all images in common is smaller than the scrollableArea-div. So all you have to do is to check if there are enough images to fill the scrollableArea. If not, you don't need the SmoothDivScroll anyway.
I have some example code:

```
... html is already in in DOM ...

imagesLoaded( '#myScrollable', function( element )
{
    var $myScrollable = $(element.elements); // just one #myScrollable
    var imgWidths = 0;
    var images = $myScrollable.find('img');
    for(var loop=0; loop < images.length; loop++)
        imgWidths += $(images[loop]).width();
    if( imgWidths > $myScrollable.width() )
    {
        $myScrollable.smoothDivScroll(
        {
            manualContinuousScrolling: true
        });
        $myScrollable.smoothDivScroll("recalculateScrollableArea");
    }
});
```

But I have to say, that I used a plugin (imagesLoaded) from https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded to have an event when all images are loaded. Otherwise all images have a size of "0";

I hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because of stuff like: `margin: 0 auto;`

Fixed it with the following:

SET UP EVENTS FOR SCROLLING RIGHT:

```
var x = e.pageX - (this.offsetLeft + el.data("scrollerOffset").left);
```

Changed to

```
var x = el.data("hotSpotWidth") + (e.pageX - el.data("scrollerOffset").left - 960);
```

SET UP EVENTS FOR SCROLLING LEFT:

```
var x = ((this.offsetLeft + el.data("scrollerOffset").left + el.data("hotSpotWidth")) - e.pageX);
```

Changed to

```
var x = el.data("hotSpotWidth") - (e.pageX - el.data("scrollerOffset").left);
```